# How to convert awk one-liner to standalone script?

Tags: awk, gawk

How can i rewrite this `awk` one-liner as a standalone script?  I want to improve readability to help me understand how it works.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==FNR{for(i=2;i<=7;i++) if($i!="\"\"") a[$1]=a[$1] FS $i;next} {n=split(a[$1],f,FS); if(n>7)n=7; for(i=2;i<=n;i++) $i=f[i]}1' csv{,}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to write it in an awk script. *.awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax is unchecked and unexamined, so i have no idea what it does or if it works.  I have just reformatted the one-liner as a standalone awk script and added some whitespace to improve readability.  If the original one-liner worked, this should too.  if not, it won't.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}

NR==FNR { 
  for(i=2;i<=7;i++) if($i!="\"\"") a[$1]=a[$1] FS $i;
  next
}
{
 n=split(a[$1],f,FS);
 if(n>7)n=7;
 for(i=2;i<=n;i++) $i=f[i]
}
1
```

Save it to a file (e.g. `myscript.awk`), make it executable (`chmod +x myscript.awk`) and run it as:

```
./myscript.awk csv{,}
```

Comment: Answering these garbage questions does no-one any favours...

Comment: i'm not so sure it is a garbage question.  the OP's English is poor, but asking how to reformat a one-liner so that it's a) standalone and b) more readable isn't a bad question.  IMO it can be a good question because it indicates a desire to learn.

Comment: It's garbage because a) there isn't a question, and b) OP can't be bothered to attempt to turn it in to one. This just enables that sort of behaviour...

Comment: there's a question in the title.  admittedly very bad english but that's not a reason to dismiss it out of hand.  i managed to understand what he wanted (and i'm very intolerant of poor english, at least for native speakers.  ESL i'm far more tolerant of)

Comment: Read his second comment. You still think this is legit? Fine.

Comment: I can't understand his second comment. makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: I just wanted to better understand the code, I had some doubts. Sorry of my poor english

Comment: @cas You seem to have formulated a better question that the OP.  You may want to take a stab are re-writing the question to match your answer before others close it.

Comment: @jasonwryan  I think Criatos means (multi-line) script as opposed to one-liner.  I think it's a valid question and a good answer.  Very basic question but still valid.  What is a good style for multi-line awk scripts?  One-liners are difficult to read and interpret.